# Is "all of shudders" a valid expression?

Tags: expressions

A google search didn't come up with a single good example, but would it be okay to say something like:

He was all of shudders.

Comment: I would interpret this as a (perhaps unintentional) variation on "[all a-shudder](https://www.google.com/search?q="all+a-shudder")," which turns out to be a bit more widely used than I was expecting it to be. I would like the questioner to provide some more context for this expression, please.

Comment: I may or may not have heard the expression somewhere before, but I was just trying to think of a way to describe a person shuddering for whatever reason, be it fear, nervousness, etc.  Perhaps "all a shudder" is what I was trying to think of.

Answer (score 1):

Of course its OK, English is very malleable and you can write whatever you like; with luck your coinage may take off and become idiomatic.

That said, the usage you propose is not one that I am familiar with and that may or may not be  a good thing.

Unfamiliar usage will tend to make the reader slow down and apply more thought as to the writer's intention. On reflection, the meaning you are getting at seems clear - that the person was shaking uncontrollably in response to some emotion, probably a negative one although excitement is a possibility.

If your intention is to provoke this reflection then embrace the usage, if your intention is clarity and rapidity of understanding, avoid it.